# How to create a `BatchRequest` that returned a specific batch?

Tags: great-expectations

I am trying to create a `BatchRequest` that filters using `data_connector_query` that I previously defined in the datasource as `group_names` for the `default_regexp` pertaining to an `InferredAssetS3DataConnector`.

Here's the datasource config:

```py
 config = {
    "name": self.config_id,
    "class_name": "Datasource",
    "execution_engine": {"class_name": "PandasExecutionEngine"},
    "data_connectors": {
        "sirene_update_s3_connector": {
            "class_name": "InferredAssetS3DataConnector",
            "bucket": self.bucket,
            "prefix": self.prefix,
            "default_regex": {
                "pattern": r"(.*)\/(.*)\/technical_date=(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\/(.*)_(\d{8})\.json",
                "group_names": [
                    "prefix",
                    "data_asset_name",
                    "year",
                    "month",
                    "day",
                    "file_name",
                    "date_suffix",
                ],
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Here are two batch_requests that i constructed differently...

```py
# Construct all the batches
batch_request_parameters = {
    "datasource_name": datasource.name,
    "data_connector_name": list(datasource.data_connectors.keys())[0],
    "data_asset_name": "asset_alpha",
}
batch_request = BatchRequest(**batch_request_parameters)
datasource.get_batch_definition_list_from_batch_request(batch_request)
```

returns:

```py
[{'datasource_name': 'my_bucket.data_pipelines.raw_data.asset_alpha', 'data_connector_name': 'asset_alpha_s3_connector', 'data_asset_name': 'asset_alpha', 'batch_identifiers': {'prefix': 'data_pipelines/raw_data', 'year': '2022', 'month': '11', 'day': '23', 'file_name': 'companies', 'date_suffix': '20221123'}},
 {'datasource_name': 'my_bucket.data_pipelines.raw_data.asset_alpha', 'data_connector_name': 'asset_alpha_s3_connector', 'data_asset_name': 'asset_alpha', 'batch_identifiers': {'prefix': 'data_pipelines/raw_data', 'year': '2022', 'month': '12', 'day': '06', 'file_name': 'companies', 'date_suffix': '20221206'}},
 {'datasource_name': 'my_bucket.data_pipelines.raw_data.asset_alpha', 'data_connector_name': 'asset_alpha_s3_connector', 'data_asset_name': 'asset_alpha', 'batch_identifiers': {'prefix': 'data_pipelines/raw_data', 'year': '2022', 'month': '12', 'day': '12', 'file_name': 'companies', 'date_suffix': '20221212'}},
 #...
 ]
```

```py
# Construct filtered batch
batch_request_parameters_2 = {
    "datasource_name": datasource.name,
    "data_connector_name": list(datasource.data_connectors.keys())[0],
    "data_asset_name": "asset_alpha",
    "data_connector_query": {
        "prefix": "data_pipelines/raw_data",
        "year": "2022",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "23",
        "file_name": "companies",
        "date_suffix": "20221123",
    },
}
batch_request_2 = BatchRequest(**batch_request_parameters_2)
datasource.get_batch_definition_list_from_batch_request(batch_request_2)
```

This raises an error...

```
BatchFilterError: Unrecognized data_connector_query key(s):
"{'file_name', 'prefix', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'date_suffix'}" detected.
```

I tested with `BatchDefinition`, and it seems to work well.

```py
from great_expectations.core.id_dict import IDDict

batch_request_parameters_3 = {
    "datasource_name": datasource.name,
    "data_connector_name": list(datasource.data_connectors.keys())[0],
    "data_asset_name": "asset_alpha",
    "batch_identifiers": IDDict({
        "prefix": "data_pipelines/raw_data",
        "year": "2022",
        "month": "11",
        "day": "23",
        "file_name": "companies",
        "date_suffix": "20221123",
    }),
}

batch_def = BatchDefinition(**batch_request_parameters_3)
datasource.get_batch_from_batch_definition(batch_def)
```

What's up with `BatchRequest`, and why can't it detect my `group_names`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

It was a trivial oversight on my part.

`data_connector_query` takes `batch_filter_parameters` as a key first, then one may pass the data identifiers.. like this

```py
"data_connector_query": {
        "batch_filter_parameters": {
            "prefix": "data_pipelines/raw_data",
            "year": "2022",
            "month": "11",
            "day": "23",
            "file_name": "companies",
            "date_suffix": "20221123",
        },
    },
```